# Sitecore Connect for Salesforce 2.0.1 - ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved

Tags: xconnect, data-exchange-framework, salesforce-connect

I installed Sitecore Connect for Salesforce 2.0.1 and added contact data using xConnect api but after executing Pipeline Batch "xConnect Contacts to Salesforce Sync" I get error message in log that "Record was not saved".

Look at part of the log file:

```
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:04 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Process Single Contact from xConnect, pipeline step: Iterate Salesforce Results and Run Pipelines, completed pipeline steps: 4)
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:04 DEBUG [Data Exchange] 25 elements were iterated. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect, pipeline step: Iterate xConnect Contacts and Run Pipelines, pipeline step identifier: ba9db2c3-87b8-46b9-83d4-6a7e28f8805b)
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:MALFORMED_ID
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Contact ID: id value of incorrect type: someExample8
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:ENTITY_IS_DELETED
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:entity is deleted
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:ENTITY_IS_DELETED
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:entity is deleted
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:ENTITY_IS_DELETED
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:entity is deleted
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS
ManagedPoolThread #11 13:58:08 ERROR [Data Exchange] Record was not saved:Email: invalid email address: Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.EmailAddress
```

Have anyone idea why this happens and how can I solve the error? It seems like some data are invalid but I am not sure why, because I used valid email addresses. At least I would like to know how to change this validation.

Comment: Is "Contact Filter" set on "Read Contact from xConnect" step?

Comment: It was not set, but when I changed value to be for example "Contact Has Preferred Email Address Key" nothing was changed.

Comment: Do you use default configuration from the branch with just your credential or you customized something like mapping and some of the pipelines?

Comment: I use default configuration without any customization.